# Populating an array from another array using multiplication inside it

Tags: java, arrays, double

as you can see below I have a variable called costperkm, usually 0.08, then I have an array based on a number, then a second array built around those numbers multiplied by costperkm, but I get the error; http://puu.sh/2sxi7

```
Scanner costscan=new Scanner(System.in);
    double costperkm = costscan.nextDouble();

double distarray[] = new double[5];

  distarray[0] = 850;
  distarray[1] = 1000;
  distarray[2] = 1250;
  distarray[3] = 1275;
  distarray[4] = 1350;
  distarray[5] = 2690;

double costarray[] = new double[5];

  costarray[0] = (distarray[0]*costperkm);
  costarray[1] = (distarray[1]*costperkm);
  costarray[2] = (distarray[2]*costperkm);
  costarray[3] = (distarray[3]*costperkm);
  costarray[4] = (distarray[4]*costperkm);
  costarray[5] = (distarray[5]*costperkm);

System.out.print(costarray[0]);
```

Comment: I don't want to click on your external link to see what error you get

Comment: Your arrays have 5 indexes but you try to access 6.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: It's just an comment about the way you name your variable, but maybe you could use camel-Case. But it's just an opinion.

Comment: @Marc-Andre Your right it would make it easier to read too.

Answer (score 5):

```
double distarray[] = new double[5];
```

Means that you only have 0-4 indexes, so:

```
distarray[5] = 2690;
```

Try to access index 5 which is out of the array.

Comment: Awesome thanks very much cant believe I forgot that!

Answer (score 1):

Your array size is 5 (0,1,2,3,4).

So index will vary from 0 to 4.

You cant access array[5]. It will throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

Look at below two expressions:

```
last_index_of_the_array != length_of_the_array    
last_index_of_the_array == length_of_the_array -1
```

If your array length is 5 your last index will 4